# Parameterized net width in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

Is something like this possible ?

`parameter width; wire[width-1] a_net = (width)'b0;`

I basically need a variable to control the width of the right hand side. I am planning to use this in an test bench where I just have to change the `parameter width at the beginning of the file`, and this parameter sets the net width in all other occurrences of `'a_net'`.

If this doesn't work - is there any other workaround ?

Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify the LSB of your wire as well:

```
parameter WIDTH = 16;

wire [WIDTH-1:0] a_net = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

In the example you could just use a localparam instead of a constant wire.

```
localparam ZERO = 'b0; // Syntax for RHS discussed below.
```

For RHS (right hand side) arguments you can use the replication operator.

```
{ WIDTH {1'b0}}; //Repeats 1'b0 WIDTH times.
```

All 1's

```
{ WIDTH {1'b1}};
```

For Max Signed (MSB == 0) mix Concatination and replication, both use `{}`

```
{1'b0, { WIDTH-1 { 1'b1 }} };
```

As of 2012 SystemVerilog can use `'0` for 0 the same width as the left hand side. `'1` All 1's.